# cocos2d-x can't change the value of the variable using lambda

Tags: c++, debugging, lambda, cocos2d-x

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool GameScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto backGroundSprite = Sprite::create("Background.jpg");
    backGroundSprite->setPosition( Point(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x,
                                         visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));
    this->addChild(backGroundSprite);


    int start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y;

    auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    touchListener->onTouchBegan = [&start_x, &start_y](Touch* touch, Event* event) -> bool {
        // your code
        auto touchPoint = touch->getLocation();
        start_x = touchPoint.x;
        start_y = touchPoint.y;
        return true;
    };

    touchListener->onTouchEnded = [start_x, start_y](Touch* touch, Event* event){
        // your code
        CCLOG("%d %d", start_x, start_y);
    };

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener,this);

    return true;
}
```

I want to capture the touching event using onTouchBegan method. I prefer to use lambda, because it is clean and elegant.

My question is:

In OnTouchEnded the value printed is not correct. Why? The value is unreasonable.

I try to move the declaration in to GameScene.h file. I can't even compile! Please help..

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2015-04-01 23:38:19.404 DR iOS[4206:72194] cocos2d: surface size: 2048x1536
2015-04-01 23:38:19.620 DR iOS[4206:72194] cocos2d: surface size: 2048x1536
32767 1382642256
32767 1382642256
32767 1382642256
32767 1382642256
```

Comment: `start_x` and `start_y` are destroyed when the function exits, because they are local variables.

Comment: thanks a lot bro! I tried to move the declare to the .h file. But I the code can't compile...

Comment: You're explicitly capturing only the variables' values for `onTouchEnded`. If you initialise them, you'll notice that you're outputting the initial values. (There's also the problem of invalid references when you capture by reference.)

Comment: Thank you :) Could you please teach me more about how to make it correct?

Comment: @shawn Not the most sophisticated software engineering solution, but it should work: Make `start_x` and `start_y` members of `GameScene`. Capture by reference. And always initialise variables.

Comment: Hi, @molbdnilo I have already tried that. But the code can't compile. It said lambda can't find the start_x and start_y...

Comment: Post the code you tried and the exact error message.

Comment: @molbdnilo I figure it out follow you suggestion. I change [&start_x, &start_y] to [&] it works